# java - error while running compiled program with external jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a simple jsoup test app in a single folder, in which there are 2 classes - LyricsGetter.java and Main.java - and a .jar file with jsoup library. When I compile the files with command `javac -cp jsoup-1.8.2.jar LyricsGetter.java Main.java` everything compiles ok, but when I try to run with `java Main`, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
    at LyricsGetter.getLyrics(LyricsGetter.java:16)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

On the other hand if I run with `java -cp jsoup-1.8.2.jar Main`, then I get `Error: Could not find or load main class Main`. So, what is the correct way to run this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Java to look for classes in `jsoup-1.8.2.jar`, *and the current folder* (`.`).

On Windows, use:

```
java -cp jsoup-1.8.2.jar;. Main
```

or on Linux, OSX, or other Unix-like systems use:

```
java -cp jsoup-1.8.2.jar:. Main
```

(The difference is that the paths are separated by `;` on Windows or `:` on *nix)